# AngularJS can't send post request with Content-Type:application/json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-http

Currently I am using angularJS and CoffeeScript to try to send a post request, and my sample code is:

```
login: (user, callback)=>
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions'
@$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseUrl,
  data: user
}).success (result)->
  callback(result)
```

But when I call it, it just send 'OPTIONS' request instead of POST request.
And the request detail is:
[image] 
If I add header to this method,

```
login: (user, callback)=>
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions'
@$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseUrl,
  data: user,
  headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}).success (result)->
  callback(result)
```

It still doesn't works, but if I change headers to  **'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'**, then it can send post requests.
But the request Content-type is not not I want.

I also try to modify the request data to JSON by:  **data: JSON.stringify(user)**, but still not working.

**UPDATES**

Guys, I did another spike on this issue. Which is I am jquery to send the request and it works fine, but I found an wired thing that is they have different request data.

**Jquery**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions",
  data: {
    "user":{
      "email":"wahxxx@gmail.com",
      "password":"123456"
    }
  },
  success: function(){

  }
```

**Screenshot for Jquery**
[image]

**Angular**

```
login: (user, callback)=>
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions'
@$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: baseUrl,
  data: {
    "user":{
      "email":"wahxxx@gmail.com",
      "password":"123456"
    }
  },
  headers:
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}).success (result)->
  callback(result)
```

Now it can send request,but I just got 401 when trying to do request.
**Screenshot for Angular**
[image]

**So I think the issue may due to the format of the angular request data.**

Comment: Also, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18834609/2674883

Comment: possible duplicate of [$http POST request with AngularJS post's my data to server but fails with error message "not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834276/http-post-request-with-angularjs-posts-my-data-to-server-but-fails-with-error)

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting CORS restrictions and same origin policy.

Easiest solution is to deploy web frontend and the api together as one app. If ports are different even on the same machine then one needs to deal with same origin policy.

Options is a preflight query. Make your backend accept it and it should be fine.

More reading:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: But why I modified the headers to 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', then it works.  By the way I am using Rails in my server side, and I've already solved that issue by setting CORS headers.

Comment: Because for that content type there is no need for OPTIONS request. I linked article: "Simple requests are requests that meet the following criteria:
HTTP Method matches (case-sensitive) one of:
HEAD
GET
POST
HTTP Headers matches (case-insensitive):
Accept
Accept-Language
Content-Language
Last-Event-ID
Content-Type, but only if the value is one of:
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain"

Comment: So you need to enable OPTIONS on rails side. Probably per action method.

Comment: I didn't send OPTIONS request, why the POST request became a OPTIONS  request? Even I request a non-existing URL, it's still became a OPTIONS request.

Comment: It is the browser. It sees that it needs to apply the security policy and make it automatic for you. So you just need to make your server side respond properly.

Comment: Hi @stride, I've already have made the changes to my rails side, but still not working. In my application Controller I have:  def allow_cors
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = %w{GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD}.join(",")
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = %w{Accept Accept-Language Content-Language Last-Event-ID Content-Type}.join(",")
    head(:ok) if request.request_method == "OPTIONS"
  end   .I also have before_filter :allow_cors in my target controller class.

Comment: I am unable to help you with rails side of things. I use different backend stack.